# Tkinter not showing any images

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Here's my problem, when I run the following code a very small window appears and if I resize it I can see the correct image names cycling but no images. I know I need to save a reference of the image object to keep it from getting garbage collected, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that given the situation.

```
from itertools import cycle
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
class App(tk.Tk):
    '''Tk window/label adjusts to size of image'''
    def __init__(self, image_files, x, y, delay):
        # the root will be self
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        # set x, y position only
        self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x, y))
        self.delay = delay
        # allows repeat cycling through the pictures
        # store as (img_object, img_name) tuple
        self.pictures = cycle((tk.PhotoImage(image), image)for image in image_files)
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack()
    def show_slides(self):
        '''cycle through the images and show them'''
        # next works with Python26 or higher
        img_object, img_name = next(self.pictures)
        self.picture_display.config(image=img_object)
        # shows the image filename, but could be expanded
        # to show an associated description of the image
        self.title(img_name)
        self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides)
    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()
# set milliseconds time between slides
delay = 3500
# get a series of gif images you have in the working folder
# or use full path, or set directory to where the images are
image_files = []
for number in range(1,10):
    image_files.append("DPS%05d.jpx" % number)
# upper left corner coordinates of app window
x = 100
y = 50
app = App(image_files, x, y, delay)
app.show_slides()
app.run()
```

Comment: what part of "saving a reference" do you not understand? What have you tried?

Comment: Well I created an instance of the class App(), doesn't that save my image from being garbage collected since I'm assigning the images to self.pictures?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, but I'm not really sure. Remember to have a `.gif` image

```
from itertools import cycle
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
class App(tk.Tk):
    '''Tk window/label adjusts to size of image'''
    def __init__(self, image_files, x, y, delay):
        # the root will be self
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        # set x, y position only
        self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x, y))
        self.delay = delay
        # allows repeat cycling through the pictures
        # store as (img_object, img_name) tuple
        for image in image_files:
            self.pictures = ((tk.PhotoImage(image), image))

        self.picture_display = tk.Label(image = self.pictures)
        self.picture_display.pack()
    def show_slides(self):
        '''cycle through the images and show them'''
        # next works with Python26 or higher
        self.picture_display.config(image=self.pictures)
        # shows the image filename, but could be expanded
        # to show an associated description of the image
        self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides)
    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()
# set milliseconds time between slides
delay = 3500
# get a series of gif images you have in the working folder
# or use full path, or set directory to where the images are
image_files = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for x in list(image_files):
    image_files.append("DPS%05d.gif" % x)
# upper left corner coordinates of app window
x = 100
y = 50
app = App(image_files, x, y, delay)
app.show_slides()
app.run()
```

This is just a stab in the dark kind of thing but it might work (i hope so), with only like 6 views i figured anything might be helpful.